# Deletion in wxpython's list control

Tags: python, wxpython

My code is generating following error-
"Couldn't retrieve information about list control item 3".

```
import wx

DATA = [("0", "Zero"), ("1", "One"), ("2", "Two")]
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "Index")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, "Number")       
        for data in DATA:
            self.list.Append((data[0], data[1]))

        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Delete")
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.list, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, e):
        current_items = self.list.GetItemCount()
        while ((current_items) >= 0) :
            if (self.list.GetItemText(current_items) == "1" or self.list.GetItemText(current_items-1) == "2"):
                self.list.DeleteItem(current_items)
                wx.MessageBox("Delete item ", 'Delete Information',wx.OK)
            else:
                break
            current_items-=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    win = MainWindow(None)
    win.Centre()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?
And what should i do to resolve this error?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted something like this?

```
import wx

DATA = [("0", "Zero"), ("1", "One"), ("2", "Two")]
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "Index")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, "Number")       
        for data in DATA:
            self.list.Append((data[0], data[1]))

        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Delete")
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.list, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, e):
        current_items = self.list.GetItemCount() - 1
        while ((current_items) >= 0) :
            if (self.list.GetItemText(current_items) == "1" or self.list.GetItemText(current_items) == "2"):
                self.list.DeleteItem(current_items)
                wx.MessageBox("Delete item ", 'Delete Information',wx.OK)
            else:
                break
            current_items-=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    win = MainWindow(None)
    win.Centre()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: its working but not completely deleting list control that means not deleting 0th index item i.e. '0'. how will items remove completely.

Comment: this is working great... but in case if i have to delete these list items dynamically, then what will be the if cndition..?

Comment: It depends on what you want to delete, i.e., what is your "if" condition. You should state your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
   def OnButton(self, e):
    itemIndex = self.list.GetNextItem(itemIndex,
                                         wx.LIST_NEXT_ALL,
                                         wx.LIST_STATE_SELECTED);
    print itemIndex
    if itemIndex == -1: 
        print "Nothing Selected";

        # // Got the selected item index
     print "SELECTED:",self.list.GetItemText(itemIndex);
```

try something like that

Comment: that sounds like homework .... this method works fine ... (It doesnt delete ... it just gets the selected index)